# In C, strings giving me warnings about initialization discarding qualifiers

Tags: c

I am getting the following warning for two lines of my code.

```
initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

The two lines are the sources of the warning.

```
function (const char *input) {
  char *str1 = input;
  char *str2 = "Hello World\0";
}
```

I think the first line gives an error because I try to assign a const char* to a char*. How would I fix that?

Comment: Why do you have "\0" on your string?  Strings in quotes are already null-terminated.  When you say "abc" you get 4-bytes, the last one being 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare it const:

```
const char *str1 = input;
```

Comment: `char *str2 = "Hello World";` is not deprecated. Why are you saying that?

Comment: That was what I was taught. Is that not the case?

Comment: Hello, I want to declare it as a char * because the value of str1 will change a lot throughout the function. And if I cast it as a const, I will not be able to change the contents of the char *. Also, I do not want to set an exact size for str2 because of the same reason. I need to manipulate the string a lot, and giving it a fixed size will prevent me from manipulating the string.

Comment: @user118321, absolutely not. The two cases aren't even semantically equivalent!

Comment: In that case, you can copy `input`. For example `char *str1 = new char [ strlen (input) + 1 ]; strcpy (input, str1);` If you need more room for str2, you need to allocate it on the heap, not the stack, in a similar manner to what I've described for str1. For example `str2 = new char [ MY_MAX_STR_LEN ];`

Comment: @CarlNorum, OK I've updated it to remove that info, then. I'll see if I can figure out what it was I was mistaking for that.

Comment: @user1118321 I don't know who told you that, it perfectly ok to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void function (const char *input) {
 char *str1 = input;
 char *str2 = "Hello World\0";
}
```

in C an object of type `char *` cannot be initialized with an object of type `const char *`.

You have do this instead:

```
const char *str1 = input;
```

Also a string literal like `"Hello World"` is already null terminated, there is no need to add the null character yourself, do this instead:

```
char *str2 = "Hello World";
```

Comment: Well, at least without an explict cast it can't.

Comment: @CarlNorum With an explicit cast of `char *`, it would no longer be a value of type `const char *` that initializes `str1`.

Comment: Well, that's splitting hairs pretty finely.  You're still initializing it with the pointer value passed into the function.  Which is not to say it's safe, which is the reason the error exists in the first place.